# if $G$ is a tree and no path in $G$ has length greater than 2 then what kind of graph must $G$ be?

Tags: graph-theory

I am not really sure, what the graph shall it be? Greater then 2, and tree.

is it a rooted tree?

Comment: Have you tried drawing some examples? Also, a rooted tree is just a tree in which some vertex is distinguished as the root. So any tree could be a rooted tree if you distinguish a root, but the conditions you are given don't have anything to do with distinguishing a root.

Answer (score 2):

G is a [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)). ([MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StarGraph.html))

Answer (score 0):

If the number of vertices in the graph is greater than one, then it must be a star graph. If it has just a single vertex then it is just a singleton graph.

Answer (score 0):

G is a tree implies that it contains no cycle and it is connected. G contains no path of length greater than 2 implies that if we start from an vertex of the graph, we can only reach two other vertices in a row. Thus, this gives us a graph that looks like this:

[image]

Such a graph is called a star graph or a complete bipartite graph $K_{1,k}$. It's composed of a vertex x and its neighborhood such that x is linked to all its neighbors but each of its neighbors is only linked to x.